# foreign key called in another serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was looking at the serialzier part in django rest framework. I saw the following models in an example

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

Here you see album is the foreign key in `Track` model and when we are serializing we are using this foreign key in Album Serializer.

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Can anyone explain me the difference in calling the album foreign key in Tracks because it is used there versus the album foreign key used in Album?

Comment: you want list of albums or list of tracks?

Answer (score 0):

if you not declare tracks field in AlbumSerializer result of serializeing is list of foreign Kys. but in this case result in tracks is a list of json objects displayed all field of Track

Answer (score 0):

The album is the query information you are given and you are trying to retrieve rows from the track table which belong to that album to include in the response.

```
{'album_name': 'Revolver',
'artist': 'The Beatles'
'tracks': ['Taxman', 'Eleanor Rigby'...]}
```